# mySQL on duplicate, update.... IF statement Question

Tags: mysql

Question I can't seem to find a clear answer to.  When you do a mySQL add/or update if duplicate with an IF statement attached to an update field, does the IF statement reference the existing Data or the new data?

ie:

```
INSERT INTO images(image_id, image, description, image_owner, image_date) 
              VALUES(
              %d, 
              %s, 
              %s, 
              %s,
              NOW()) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
              UPDATE 
                image=%s, 
                description=%s,
                **image_owner=IF(description IS NULL, %s, image_owner), **
                image_date=NOW(), ...values for %s...);
```

So this is basically used if an admin comes and edits the description/image but wants to make sure credit stays w/the original user. So for this part: does the if(description IS NULL,..) section check to see if the description related to this record is already in the DB is NULL, or the description from the new update is null?

Comment: `description` refers to the existing Data.

Comment: 'In assignment value expressions in the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause, you can use the VALUES(col_name) function to refer to column values from the INSERT portion of the INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement. ' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `UPDATE` part of the query, `description` refers to the existing value in the table. If you want to use the value from the `INSERT` portion of the query, use `VALUES(description)`.

Comment: Thank you, I was having issues with this and realized it was way easier to just separate this into 2 queries and implement this logic pre-SQL query.  Lesson learned, remove as much logic as possible from queries when you can!